# Passing a Node as an XSL Template Parameter

Tags: xslt

In an existing XSL stylesheet I was passing a string into a named template. Due to a requirements change, I now need to display four strings, the string I was displaying and its three siblings. Rather than pass the four separate strings into the named template, I'm trying to pass their parent element (PETrailingFund in the code below),

```
 <xsl:call-template name="row">
  <xsl:with-param name="label">Price/Earnings Trailing</xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="formatMarker">x</xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="fund" select="PETrailingFund" />
  <xsl:with-param name="benchmark">
    <xsl:value-of select="benchmark/PETrailingBenchmark"/>
  </xsl:with-param>
  <xsl:with-param name="benchmark2">
    <xsl:value-of select="benchmark2/PETrailingBenchmark"/>
  </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

but the transformation blows up when I try to work with the "fund" parameter in the named template:

```
<xsl:template name="row">
  <xsl:param name="label" />
  <xsl:param name="fund" />
  <xsl:param name="benchmark">NOT PROVIDED</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="benchmark2">NOT PROVIDED</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="formatMarker">&#160;</xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="useDecimalFormatter">yes</xsl:param>
  <tr>
    <td class="first popup">
      <xsl:value-of select="$label" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <xsl:if test="$benchmark = 'NOT PROVIDED'">
        <xsl:attribute name="class">last</xsl:attribute>
      </xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="$fund/child::*" />
      <xsl:value-of select="$formatMarker"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

From what I've read, I'm not really passing in a node but a result tree fragment and I need to get it back to a node (or node-set). Is that accurate or am I doing something else wrong? How would I convert it (I'm working in a fairly stock PHP5 environment that I can't change).

N.B., I trimmed a good bit of the named template for simplicity's sake.

Comment: I don't understand what it means that "the transformation blows up". In your XSLT code sample `$fund` is an instance of node set data type, not RTF.

Comment: It should be, but it isn't in 1.0. It comes in as a string instead of a node. Or something like that. This was a while ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nasty thing in XSLT 1.0. In 2.0 this happens automatically. In 1.0 you need a custom function, often called blah:node-set. It is available in many XSLT toolkits (I don't know yours or PHP). If you have access to EXSLT, it contains one too. Example: http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html

Comment: The link is now broken. If only you had shown an example inline here on Stackoverflow...

Comment: I've added a link to another article that shows the use of node-set(). As it requires a lot of context and multiple documents, I prefer not to copy in the code, but link to a full example.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing an

```
<xsl:call-template..>
```

, have you instead tried to do an

```
<xsl:apply-templates..>
```

on the node or node set in question?

Comment: You can't call a named template with apply-templates. Am I missing something?

Comment: Correct, you can't.  I was just recommending you recode the template with match="YourNode" instead of a named template.  I believe you can still pass params to this as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't do that as I'm using the template against a number of different nodes.

Comment: Sure you can:  <xsl:template match="YourNode1|YourNode2|YourNode3">

Comment: Sorry, not quite what I meant. I know you can have it match different nodes, but I want to control when it gets called.

Answer (score 1):

In a follow up to Keith's suggestion, you can use the mode="x" to only apply the call-templates when that mode is set.

Yes, I know this question is pretty old, but I stumbled on it while looking for something else and figured I'd chime in for any future visitors.